# invalid syntax tried almost everything

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm running into issues with this code:

```
return render(request, 'count.html',{'fulltext':fulltext,'count':len(wordlist),'worddictionary':worddictionary.items("")})
```

CMD is telling me line 22 invalid syntax but, I cant find anything wrong with it.

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render
    import operator

    def homepage(request):
        return render(request, 'home.html')

    def count(request):
        fulltext = request.GET['fulltext']

        wordlist = fulltext.split()

worddictionary = {}
for word in wordlist:
    if word in worddictionary:
        #increase
        worddictionary[word] += 1

    else:
        #add to the dictionary
        worddictionary[word] = 1
sortedwords = sorted(worddictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

return render(request, 'count.html',{'fulltext':fulltext,'count':len(wordlist),'worddictionary':worddictionary.items()})

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're _missing_ the value for the **last item** in your context dictionary.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your code I am seeing that you are giving the  key value pair of the dictionary like : 'count':len(word list) . I suggest you to make a new variable suppose x=len(word list) and then use this in the dictionary like that 'count':x. I hope it will get resolves after that.

Answer (score 0):

That may be because of an extra ' at the end of your return statement.